# AOSP - Custom System Update

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, android-settings, android-update-app

I've been searching for about two days for a way to receive informations about System updates in Nougat 7.1.2.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I need to to make it more accessible for our type of users (but still be able to use the Google Over-The-Air system for my device).

I already know that it is possible to start the default SystemUpdateActivity by using:

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.update.SystemUpdateActivity
```

Although, I'd like to avoid calling another activity to achieve this.

I've been searching for any kind of BroadcastReceiver or Action but couldn't find anything clearly functional.